# When and how should I use exception handling?

Tags: c++, windows, exception

I am reading about exception handling. I got some information about what exception handling is, but I have a few questions:

1. When to throw an exception?
2. Instead of throwing an exception, can we use a return value to indicate the error?
3. If I protect all my functions by try-catch blocks, won't it reduce the performance?
4. When to use exception handling?
5. I saw a project where each and every function in that project contained a try-catch block (i.e. code inside the entire function is surrounded by try-catch block). Is this a good practice?
6. What is the difference between try-catch and __try __except?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4105060/when-to-catch-exceptions

Comment: You'll need to ask more specific questions than "When to throw an exception". You throw an exception when something exceptional happens.

Comment: I wrote about this relative to PHP, but I think pretty much everything is applicable to C++. Check out [the blog post](http://blog.ircmaxell.com/2011/08/error-handling-in-php.html).

Answer (score 112, accepted):

Here's quite comprehensive guide on exceptions that I think is a Must Read:

Exceptions and error handling - [C++ FAQ](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/exceptions) or [C++ FAQ lite](http://www.cs.uregina.ca/Links/class-info/210/C++FAQ/exceptions.html)

As a general rule of thumb, throw an exception when your program can identify an *external* problem that prevents execution. If you receive data from the server and that data is invalid, throw an exception. Out of disk space? Throw an exception. Cosmic rays prevent you from querying the database? Throw an exception. But if you get some invalid data from inside your very own program - don't throw an exception. If your problem comes from your own bad code, it's better to use ASSERTs to guard against it. Exception handling is needed to identify problems that program cannot handle and tell them about the user, because user can handle them. But bugs in your program are not something the user can handle, so program crashing will tell not much less than "Value of answer_to_life_and_universe_and_everything is not 42! This should never happen!!!!11" exception.

Catch an exception where you can do something useful with it, like, display a message box. I prefer to catch an exception once inside a function that somehow handles user input. For example, user presses button "Annihilate all hunams", and inside annihilateAllHunamsClicked() function there's a try...catch block to say "I can't". Even though annihilation of hunamkind is a complex operation that requires calling dozens and dozens of functions, there is only one try...catch, because for a user it's an atomic operation - one button click. Exception checks in every function are redundant and ugly.

Also, I can't recommend enough getting familiar with RAII - that is, to make sure that all data that is initialized is destroyed automatically. And that can be achieved by initializing as much as possible on stack, and when you need to initialize something on heap, use some kind of smart pointer. Everything initialized on the stack will be destroyed automatically when an exception is thrown. If you use C-style dumb pointers, you risk memory leak when an exception is thrown, because there is noone to clean them up upon exception (sure, you can use C-style pointers as members of your class, but make sure they are taken care of in destructor).

Comment: Thanks for u r valuable input. 
>“Exception handling is needed to identify problems that program >cannot handle and tell them about the user, because user can >handle them”
Instead of throwing an exception I can return the error value and in the calling function i can check for the error and display a message which will help the user to handle it.

Comment: Take a look at the FAQ again, particularly at the third and fourth code snippets in this section: http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/exceptions.html#faq-17.2 Exceptions are great, because they let your errors surface from any depth of call stack... It's like if error codes are bathyspheres, exceptions are submarines :)

Comment: @Septagram
"If your problem comes from your own bad code, it's better to use ASSERTs to guard against it.":

An assert won't let you continue with tasks that don't rely on the buggy branch (just because your program has a bug in one function doesn't mean it can't do other useful things). It will not let you use custom loggers. It will bypass the destructors you benefit from by using RAII (want your file buffers to be flushed before the program terminates? Better not skip those destructors with `fclose` then!). It will not give you a full stacktrace.

Comment: Something to say about RAII and "dumb pointers". Just because you use a "dumb pointer" doesn't mean that you are not following RAII. Remember that it's only when you allocate system resources that you need to make sure they are deallocated. A pointer is simply a variable on the stack that holds a memory address. Object allocation and initialization is not required to use a "dumb pointer". A "dumb pointer" can simply hold the address of an object that is allocated elsewhere, and is perfectly fine to use. (cont. in next comment)

Comment: You might have a Renderer object that stores the address of the Display object in a pointer in order to draw things to the Display, but you can't use a smart pointer because a smart pointer will destroy the Display object when you destroy the Renderer object, which you don't want to happen. In this case, either "dumb pointer" or a reference are the only ways to go.

Answer (score 15):

Exceptions are useful in a variety of circumstances.

First, there are some functions where the cost of calculating the pre-condition is so high it is better to just do the calculation and abort with an exception if it is found the pre-condition is not met. For example, you cannot invert a singular matrix, however to calculate if it is singular you calculate the determinant which is very expensive: it may have to be done inside the function anyhow, so just "have a try" at inverting the matrix and report an error if you can't by throwing an exception. This is basically an **exception as negative pre-condition** usage.

Then there are other cases where your code is already complex and passing error information up the call chain is difficult. This is partly because C and C++ have broken data structure models: there are other, better ways, but C++ doesn't support them (such as using monads in Haskell). This use is basically **I couldn't be bothered to do it right so I'll throw an exception**: its not the right way but it's practical.

Then there is the main use of exceptions: to report when external pre-conditions or invariants, such as sufficient resources like memory or disk space, are not available. In this case you will usually terminate the program, or a major subsection of it, and the exception is a good way of transmitting information about the problem. **C++ Exceptions were designed for reporting errors which prevent the program continuing**.

The exception handling model used in most modern languages including C++ is **known** to be broken. It is vastly too powerful. Theoreticians have now developed better models than the completely open "throw anything" and "maybe and maybe not catch it" model. In addition using type information to classify exceptions wasn't a very good idea.

So the best thing you can do is **throw exceptions sparingly, when there's an actual error, and when there's no other way to deal with it** and **catch exceptions as close to the throw point as possible**.

Comment: Could you add some links/references for "exception handling is known to be broken" and "Theoreticians have now developed better models", please?

Comment: A critical thing which often needs to be known when catching exceptions, but about which most exceptions provide no useful data, is whether the code which threw the exception has had any effect on the state of the system.  Do any of the theoreticians' models deal with this?

Comment: @JurajBlaho I tried to find the links/references you are talking about without success. Can you edit his answer to add them at the end?

Comment: I agree with example #1 and #3. However, I do think that if the code is too complex so your thinking about throwing an exception maybe you would need some refactoring.

Assert are also a good way (even better) to check if the code is running properly and it is actually less expensive than exception.

I recommend 2 chapters (Assertive Programming and When to use Exceptions) from the book: The Pragmatic Programmer, to anyone interested in this subject.

Comment: @ForceMagic: I don't have any such links. That is why I have asked Yttrill to add them to support his claims.

Comment: No need for links. Use brains. You can throw an exception which isn't caught. That's bad. Worse than goto since goto at least always goes somewhere. Static typing can't cope with exception specifications: there's no sane system where polymorphic functions can have an exception specification because it is dependent on the particular instance of the type variable. Note these removed from new C++ Standard. The new model is called "delimited continuations"
: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delimited_continuation

Comment: BTW: C++ exceptions are particularly evil because you're throwing a value of any type. Compare with Ocaml exceptions where every program has a finite number of declared exception constructors. Compare also with (my language) Felix, which allows non-local gotos which are statically assured to have a target, and then allows them to be wrapped in closures and passed to the calculating function. Here that function aborts with a client supplied handler, not one it invents itself. As if you passed in C++ catch clauses, and you throw the catch clause (not an arbitrary object).

Comment: The advantage of the Felix scheme is you cannot "forget" to pass in an error handler, since it is part of the function signature, and you cannot throw something that can't be caught. It's statically safe. It still isn't very satisfactory (who like gotos?) but it's one heck of a lot better than throwing arbitrary objects as exceptions.

Comment: This comment is very Java-esque and wrong. I totally disagree that you should be using exceptions to do pre-condition checks or error reporting.  C++ exceptions are more 'stop the world' events and are more akin to 'panic' in golang that a Java/Python exception.

Answer (score 5):

> If your problem comes from your own bad code, it's better to use ASSERTs to guard against it. Exception handling is needed to identify problems that program cannot handle and tell them about the user, because user can handle them. But bugs in your program are not something the user can handle, so program crashing will tell not much

I disagree with this aspect of [the accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4506872/451601).  An assert is not hands-down better than throwing an exception.  If exceptions were suitable only for run-time errors (or "external problems") , what is `std::logic_error` for?

A logic error is almost by definition the kind of condition that prevents a program from continuing.  If the program is a logical construct, and a condition occurs outside the domain of that logic, how can it continue?  Gather ye inputs while ye may, and throw an exception!

It's not like there's not prior art.  `std::vector`, to name but one, throws a logic error exception, namely `std::out_of_range`.  If you use the standard library and don't have a top-level handler to catch standard exceptions -- if only to call **what**() and **exit**(3) -- then your programs are subject to abrupt silent, termination.

An assert macro is a much weaker guard.  There is no recovery.  Unless, that is, you're not running a debug build, in which case there's *no execution*.  The assert macro belongs to an era when computation was 6 orders of magnitude slower than today.  If you're going to the trouble to test for logic errors, but not to use that test when it counts, in production, you'd better have a lot of confidence in your code!

The standard library provides for logic error exceptions, and employs them.  They are there for a reason: because logic errors occur, and are exceptional.  Just because C features assertions is no reason to rely on such a primitive (and, arguably, useless) mechanism, when an exception handles the job so much better.

Comment: I would not justify something just *"because The Standard Library"* did it. There have been some ugly and inconsistent things within the STD.

Answer (score 3):

Best read for this

Exception handling has been talked about a lot over the last decade and a half. However, despite a general consensus on how to properly handle exceptions, a divide on usage continues to exist. Improper exception handling is easy to spot, easy to avoid, and is a simple code (and developer) quality metric. I know absolute rules come off as close minded or exaggerated, but as a general rule you shouldn’t be using try/catch

http://codebetter.com/karlseguin/2010/01/25/don-t-use-try-catch/

Comment: Isn't that article really trying to say, don't use `try` / `catch {}`?

Answer (score 2):

1.An exception check is included in the code when there is a possibility of getting an exception as a result or somewhere in between the problem.

2.Use try-catch block with only those cases where it is required. Usage of each try-catch block add to an extra condition check that certainly reduces the optimization of the code.

3.I think _try_except is a valid variable name....

Comment: FYI, __try and __except are for Microsoft's Structured Exception Handling (SEH). http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s58ftw19(v=vs.80).aspx

Answer (score 0):

**The basical difference is:**

1. one make error handling for you.
2. an one is you do your own.

   - For instance, you have an expression could make `0 divide error`.  Using try catch `1.` will help you when error occurred. Or you need an `if a==0 then..` in `2.`
   - If you dont try catch the exception I dont think its faster, its just simply bypass, if `error` occurred it will be `threw` to an outer handler.

Handing yourself mean the problem not go further then have advantage in speed in many case, but not always.

**Suggest:** Just handling yourself when it simple and in logically case.

Answer (score -2):

Many C/C++ purists discourage exceptions altogether. The main criticisms are:

1. It's slow - Of course it isn't really "slow". However, compared to pure c/c++, there is quite a bit of overhead.
2. It introduces bugs - If you don't handle exceptions properly, you can miss the clean-up code in the function that throws the exception.

Instead, check the return value / error code every time you call a function.

Comment: Nonsense.  First, we're talking C++ - there is no "C/C++", and of course C-only programmers would be uncomfortable with exceptions.  "pure C/C++" doesn't exist, and exceptions are a part of "pure C++" - they're in the Standard.  You can write buggy exception-handling code, and you can write buggy error-returning code, or buggy error-state code - it's misleading to characterise exceptions as being more error prone in general.  Sorry, but this is some of the worst advice I've seen on S.O.

Comment: Mark me down if you like, but coming from a C background, I can tell you that myself and many many others refrain from using exceptions altogether.

Comment: 1. It's only slow when an exception is actually thrown. And exceptions are called exceptions, because they are only thrown in exceptional circumstances. Program throwing over 9000 exceptions per second is doing it wrong. 2. If you take care not to do memory management with pure new-delete, cleanup will be done for you. C-style memory management is by far more error-prone than exceptions. 3. Checking return value adds a lot of extra lines of code, thus making it less readable and less maintainable.

Comment: 1) depending on the compiler that may not be true. And all exceptions add a good amount of byte-code increasing executable size and slowing things down. 2) pure new-delete is used all the time, not everything can be a stack object. 3) checking return values may be more lines of code, but it is arguably more maintainable. You may not agree, but it's a generally accepted reasonable belief that C++ exceptions are bad in many cases. Take a look at embedded-C++ as an example.

Comment: 11 downvotes and 8 upvotes. I think it's clear that while this opinion does not reflect the general consensus, there is a large contingent of developers who are warry of exceptions for the reasons I described.

Comment: @speedplane It's already another two years after you came back to a decade old answer, so excuse the obnoxious necro reply, but I think the main problem with this answer isn't that people love exceptions. I personally prefer to avoid them whenever I can, and modern programming languages are mostly moving away from them and back to in-band error handling with algebraic types.

More likely people just disagree with this particular definition of "purity" and promotion of "C-style" C++. Like I said above, I don't like exceptions, but this style is the opposite of what I would call "pure C++".