# Python: with statement and execption handling

Tags: python, with-statement

I give following code snippet,
As at the end of the code I am getting blank output file

in with context when exception is raised The file is closed and again overridden in next iteration

```
with open('output', 'w') as f:
    try:
        for i in range(1, 100):
             if i % 2 == 0:
                 f.write('%d \n' % i)
             else:
                 raise Exception()
    except Exception as e: 
        pass
```

Is my understanding correct? 
If so, Why this behavior is there?As I am handling the exception.

Is it right that `with` statement will always close files
whenever exception is raised in side block.

What could be possible solution using `with` statement?

Comment: I'm confused by what you're asking. Are you asking why does the `for` loop end when the exception is raised, instead of just continuing with the next?

Comment: Is your question why the file is overwritten? If so, the answer to that is that `w` always creates a new file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using a `try`/`except` block, the `try` block is not continued upon completion of the `except` block.

A possible solution would be to replace the `raise Exception()` statement - which is currently raising a meaningless exception - with a `pass` statement instead.

In fact, you should probably do a little reading regarding [when to use exceptions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4506369/when-and-how-should-i-use-exception-handling).

Comment: ohh , yes i got. mistake :)